# HeightRequest is not honored if content is added below

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to lock the height of a header - or basically any kind of content on the top of a page. However, once scrollable content is added below the height changes. A simple example:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0" Spacing="0">
            <Frame Margin="0" HeightRequest="150" BackgroundColor="red" CornerRadius="0" HasShadow="False" Padding="0"></Frame>
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

This works fine. However, adding a lot of simple label lines in a scrollview somehow changes the height of the frame.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="0" Margin="0" Spacing="0">
            <Frame Margin="0" HeightRequest="150" BackgroundColor="red" CornerRadius="0" HasShadow="False" Padding="0"></Frame>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="aaa" /> <!-- Repeated 54 times however removed here for simplicity-->
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The results end up like this:

[image]

Why does it happen and can I do anything to avoid it? And why is the height reduced to exactly that height? Thanks!

Comment: FWIW: Frame (or other layout) without anything inside it, decides it can yield the height. Put a BoxView inside the frame, and give the BoxView a HeightRequest - that might do better. Still, I agree with Kevin’s answer to use Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're limiting the height of the ScrollView. So considering you're merely doing a HeightRequest, it may change as needed to fit everything.
It's usually safer to use Grids. In this example, something like this could help you:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="red" CornerRadius="0" HasShadow="False" Padding="0"></Frame>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="aaa" /> <!-- Repeated 54 times however removed here for simplicity-->
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Oh yes, I see that the grid is treated a little different and will make the desired layout. Thank you.